# Keep lines in a php array (with for())

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

My Code:

```
$RuleNameArray = array();
$dbgetreportsrulename = new DB_MSSQL;
$dbgetreportsrulename->query("Select RulesID,RulesName_Lang_$languageid as RuleName from Main_Rules");
for ($igrn=0;$igrn < $dbgetreportsrulename->num_rows();$igrn++) {

if ($dbgetreportsrulename->next_record()){  
    $dbgetreportsrulename_RuleID = $dbgetreportsrulename->f('RulesID');
    $dbgetreportsrulename_RuleName = $dbgetreportsrulename->f('RuleName');
}
$RuleNameArray = array($dbgetreportsrulename_RuleID => $dbgetreportsrulename_RuleName);
}
```

How i can keep all entry in $RuleNameArray, because now he keep only last entry.

Comment: Use [push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Comment: Please clarify what it is you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your all entry then your `$RuleNameArray` should be :

```
$RuleNameArray[$dbgetreportsrulename_RuleID] = $dbgetreportsrulename_RuleName;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this also,

```
$RuleNameArray[] = array($dbgetreportsrulename_RuleID => $dbgetreportsrulename_RuleName);
              ^
```